# Draw a html5 canvas cylindre with camera view inside the cylinder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I think the title is self-explanatory.
I need to build html5 canvas cylindre with the camera view in the center of the cylinder.
On the wall of the cylinder i need to build something like pictures, the cylinder to rotate and zoom.

If anyone has some pointers as to where to start with the camera and the cylinder please help.

To help you understand my description i have posted a image
http://s21.postimg.org/fpnmukbef/inside_cilindre.jpg

Comment: "Self-explanatory"! Not to me.

Comment: make sence with your edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you must work on the 2d picture and on last step transform the needed part

to transform the good part into 3d, i think you must stretch each colon depending on the parabola equation you choice

```
function getStretch(x,maxx)
{ /* here i choice :
     f(x) = (x*x)+3 for top
     f(x) = -(x*x)+1 for bottom
     when y >= 0 and y <= 4
     x >= -1 and x <= +1
  */

   // convert x ~ maxx to -1 ~ 1
   var ratio = 2/maxx; // -1 to 1 === 2
   x = x * ratio;
   x -= 1; // switch from 0 ~ 2 to -1 ~ 1

   var sizeY = 4;
   var y = -(x*x)+1; // bottom get y >= 0 and y <= 1 result, easier to compute
   y *= 2; // double to add up and bottom
   var colonHeight = sizeY - y;
   var colonRatio = colonHeight / sizeY;
   return colonRatio; // return the height ratio for this colon
}
```

values for a 101 colons view : http://jsfiddle.net/L9YgL/1/

```
var view_start_x = 200; // current view start at 200px from left source image
var view_size_x  = 399; // current view work on 400 px width

// get our stretch ratio for each colon
var stretch_values = [];
for(var x=0;x<=view_size_x;x++) stretch_values[x] = getStretch(x,view_size_x);

// now we need a function to get the colon height and position

var colonHeight = 400; // height of source image, and max height of out

function getColonInfo(x)
{ if(x < 0 || x > view_size_x) return {h:42,y:0};
  // compute current colon height
  var ratio  = stretch_values[x];
  var height = parseInt( colonHeight * ratio ,10);
  var posY = parseInt( (colonHeight - height)/2 ,10);
  return {h:height,y:posY};
}

// save this info for each out colon
var colon_info = [];
for(var x=0;x<=view_size_x;x++) colon_info[x] = getColonInfo(x);

// now a function to render a colon with a zoom

function renderColon(x,sourceX)
{    var info = colon_info[x];
     var originalHeight = colonHeight;
     var height = info.h;
     var y = info.y;
     // now do your reduce/blit magic here
     // render at "x","y" a colon with height of "height"
     // from source colon "sourceX" who get height of "originalHeight"

}

// and a function to iterate each colon and do the magic  

function my2dTo3d()
{
    for(x=0; x<=view_size_x; x++)
    {    var offset = x + view_start_x;
         renderColon(x,offset);
    }
}
```

ok there certainly be a better method to do this, here i do it at hand, maybe css3 ?

Comment: this is WAAAAAY cool!  Would you consider taking the time to work up a javascript demo, or maybe point me in the direction of mapping images to a cylindrical parabola....

Comment: thank you ... it's a start i will go from here .. at least i know where to begin

Comment: ok, check the slowest awesome in the world, under creative common 3.0 by-nc-sa http://jsfiddle.net/L9YgL/16/

Comment: ok in fact the good way of change parabola is to always use y = -(x*x)+1; equation and just change sizeY, exemple http://jsfiddle.net/r043v/L9YgL/23/ this will keep border in corner and just change the middle point position